# SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Tags: php, ssl, nginx, curl, https

I am getting this error:
**Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version in /home/ankurgupta/websites/control.abhinavsoftware.in/imgssl/index.php:26**

```
$fileUrl = "https://demos.abhinavsoftware.com/university/uploads/5d73a80a1d88a.jpg";
$saveTo = "ssl.jpg"; 

$fp = fopen($saveTo, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($fileUrl); //Create a cURL handle.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); //Pass our file handle to cURL.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 7); //Timeout if the file doesn't download after 20 seconds.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1);

$response  = curl_exec($ch); //Execute the request.
if(curl_errno($ch)){ //If there was an error, throw an Exception
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
} 


$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); //Get the HTTP status code. 
$errorMessage = curl_error($ch);
$errorCode = curl_errno($ch);

print_r($statusCode);
print_r($errorMessage);
print_r($errorCode);
var_dump($response);

curl_close($ch); //Close the cURL handler.
```

Same code works in my local server (Running Ubuntu 19.04). But fails in my web server (Running Ubuntu 18.04) Both running Nginx and PHP7.2 FPM

Can you help me how to fix it?

Comment: this issue is almost always caused by using an old bugged version of libcurl or ssl backend library (like an old version of openssl), what do you get from `var_dump(curl_version());`  ?

Comment: btw you should use `w+b`, if your code may ever run on MS Windows, you don't want it opened in text mode ^^ (binary downloads, like .jpg images, would become corrupted.)

Comment: @hanshenrik   ["version_number"]=>
  int(473600)
  ["age"]=>
  int(4)
  ["features"]=>
  int(4179869)
  ["ssl_version_number"]=>
  int(0)
  ["version"]=>
  string(6) "7.58.0"
  ["host"]=>
  string(19) "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
  ["ssl_version"]=>
  string(14) "OpenSSL/1.1.1c"
  ["libz_version"]=>
  string(6) "1.2.11"

Comment: can you replicate it with the curl cli program? what do you get from ```<?php var_dump(shell_exec('curl -v \'https://demos.abhinavsoftware.com/university/uploads/5d73a80a1d88a.jpg\' -o /dev/null 2>&1'));``` ?